# How do I compute these to make my BMI Calculator work?

Tags: java, if-statement, double

```
    String A;
    String B;
    Double num1, num2;

    System.out.print("Enter your weight in kg: ");
    A = br.readLine();
    num1 = Double.parseDouble(A);
    System.out.print("Enter your height in cm: ");
    B = br.readLine();
    num2 = Double.parseDouble(B);

    **double bmi = (100 * 100 * A) / (B * B);**
    System.out.println("" + bmi);

    if (bmi < 18.5) {
        System.out.println("You are underweight");
    } else if (bmi < 25) {
        System.out.println("You are normal");
    } else if (bmi < 30) {
        System.out.println("You are overweight");
    } else {
        System.out.println("You are obese");
    }
}
```

I think the problem is in this line, how do i compute these so it works? TIA! :**double bmi = (100 * 100 * A) / (B * B);**

Comment: `A` and  `B` are strings, but you converted them to doubles and put them in `num1` and `num2` respectively. So.........

Comment: `A` and `B` are strings. You had them parsed into numbers, `num1` and `num2`. Why are you trying to do the arithmetic with the strings?

Comment: Use proper variable naming. It will be likely to help you. For example `weightString`, `heightString`, `weightDouble` and `heightDouble`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning the parsed values of `A` and `B` to `num1` and `num2` respectively. `num1` & `num2` now contain the parsed values while `A` and `B` still hold their original string values. For this code to work you'd have to write it like this: `double bmi = (100 * 100 * num1) / (num2 * num2)`.

Comment: Ive been looking at this for quite a while that it started to confuse me. Thanks everyone!